# WebView with ProgressDialog , and Dismiss

Tags: java, android, webview

Anyone know how to insert ProgressDialog that will show every link clicked ; into this webview?

```
public class ChatreaMainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 [...]
        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 [...]
```

I have try with and it won't dismiss at all.

```
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(ChatreaMainActivity.this, "", "Loading Page...");
        }
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {

       if (progressBar.isShowing())
       {
          progressBar.dismiss();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.mobiinteractive.Sandbar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class SandbarinFacebook extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fb);

        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
                true);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(pd.isShowing() && pd!=null)
                {
                pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/sandbarathens");

    }
}
```